# Microwave Oven Outlet

Tags: electrical

Wondering if somebody could please let me know where I should put my receptacle for the microwave in my kitchen. It's an over the stove microwave/range hood type. I was going to install it in the section of my cabinets designated for my microwave, so basically behind my microwave. A contractor, however ; told me to instal it in the cabinet above the microwave.

Thank You

Comment: Your contractor is correct. Install it in the cabinet above the microwave.

Comment: Perfect, great piece of knowledge to add to my mind.

Comment: Curiosity: Why above, other than it being easier to unplug if required?

Comment: Maybe so it's for sure out of the way of the microwave hanging brackets?

Comment: I believe the plug needs to be accessible so you can unplug it, say if the microwave catches fire or something

Answer (score 1):

The contractor is correct. The cord from the microwave will exit from the top of the unit, and should pass through the bottom of your cabinet, and plug into an outlet inside the upper cabinet.

The microwave is designed to mount flush to the wall and the bottom of your cabinet, thus you would not be able to plug the oven into an outlet mounted on the wall behind the oven.